# Show/hide divs following cursor on half of screen width

Tags: jquery, mousemove, splidejs

I have a Splide slider with prev/next buttons following the cursor, but I can't figure out how to hide the next button div when hovering on the left side of the full width slider and then hide the prev button div when hovering on the right side of the slider?

This is my code so far:

```
<script>

$(".splide__arrow--next").html("NEXT");
$(".splide__arrow--prev").html("PREV");

// Hide arrow when cursor is outside the slider
function showArrow() {
   $(".splide__arrow").addClass('show');
}

function hideArrow() {
   $(".splide__arrow").removeClass('show');
}

$(".splide").hover(showArrow, hideArrow);

// Make div follow cursor
$(".splide").bind("mousemove", function(e){
  $(".splide__arrow--next, .splide__arrow--prev").css({
    top: e.pageY - $(".splide__arrow--next, .splide__arrow--prev").height()/2,
    left: e.pageX - $(".splide__arrow--next, .splide__arrow--prev").width()/2
  });
});

</script>
```